# Token Scanner for programming Language(Lexical Analysis)

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

[image]
This DFA is a token scanner for a programming language.I would like to add keywords of the programming language(if,else,end ... etc) in the DFA so the lexical analyzer can recognize them.

The Question is : Do i have to convert the entire given DFA to an ε-NFA(which will result in more states),add the keywords(with ε transitions too)and then convert back to a DFA or i just have to add the keywords so that the DFA becomes an NFA and then convert back to a DFA

Comment: You can do whatever you want, as long as the resulting automaton behaves correctly.

Comment: No need for any $\epsilon$. From the relevant states taken as roots, you can enter a tree-like automaton (in fact a trie) that recognizes the keywords. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1):

There's a common misunderstanding about why many construction algorithms (and most notably Thompson's) use ε-NFAs. It's not because it's *necessary* to do so, and it's not because it's *efficient* to do so.

Thompson's construction has the following advantages:

- It's recursive on the structure of the regular expression.
- It's easy to convince yourself that the construction is correct.
- It's straightforward to incorporate certain extensions (e.g. the LEX lookahead operator "/").

Real-world implementations of regular expressions, even if they are based on Thompson's construction, typically optimise a dozen or so common base cases (e.g. Kleene closure of a character set; `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` expands to something much bigger than it needs to be), saving Thompson's rules for higher levels.

Comment: Another advantage is that every state has at most two out-transitions, and if it has two they are  both epsilons. Given the memory constraints Thompson had to work within, this was a big help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you incorporate the LEX "/" operator?

Comment: The "/" operator is basically a different kind of end state that you backtrack back to. A full treatment would require understanding the exact semantics of that operator, which I don't remember.